# Trying to call a popup menu from within a ViewHolder object

Tags: android, popupmenu

I'm trying to click on an imageview in my list item in the recyclerview. I was able to call a Toast message by passing view.getContext() into the Toast method. But for some reason I can't do it. It tells me setOnMenuItemClickListener can't be applied in PopupMenu. What am I doing wrong?

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView tvName;
        public TextView tvDate;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            tvName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_name);
            tvDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.match_date);
            imageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
                    popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(view.getContext());
                    popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                    popupMenu.show();


                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "onClick working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: what do you want you `OnMenuItemClickListener` to do?

Comment: I want it to create a popup menu with 2 options (edit, and delete)

Comment: and `what do you want you OnMenuItemClickListener to do`?

Comment: when you click edit it will send the user to a different activity. when you click delete it will delete a menu item from the list

Comment: then set an `OnMenuItemClickListener` same way as you did for `OnClickListener`, and do whatever you need inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an anonymous [PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener.html) like this:

```
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){
   public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
       // your stuff here (one frequently uses a switch-case, 
       // the cases depending on item.getId() )
   } 
});
```

Comment: I'm trying that now but if I want to send the user to a different Activity from the popup menu using an intent, how do I get a context for the first parameter of the intent when I'm calling from an anonymous class inside an innerclass of a viewholder     Adapter -> ViewHolder -> ImageView(click listener) - > PopupMenu (onMenuItemClick) - >Intent?

Comment: The ViewHolder has a public field called itemView which is a View and so it has a Context

Comment: @HelpMeI'mStupid - or in your case make the Constructor parameter final and use its Context

Comment: Ok! I'm getting somewhere. I did this     Intent intent = new Intent ( itemView.getContext(), EditMatchActivity.class);  That created the intent but normally I start an activity using        startActivity(intent)     I'm getting an error with that line. I think because I'm not calling the startActivity from an Activity context. So........

Comment: itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent);        This worked!!!!      THANK YOU!!!!!! YOUR THE BEST!

Answer (score 0):

I am using some code like this to show `PopMenu` in `RecycleView`

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

               final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), imageView);
                                    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
                                    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                                                case R.id.item_edit:
                                                    // to edit

                                                    break;
                                                case R.id.item_delete:
                                                    // to delete

                                                    break;
                                            }
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    });
                                    //displaying the popup
                                    popup.show();

                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "onClick working", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

May it help you. :)

Comment: That's working well but I have one more implementation problem. I want to click on "item_delete" and create an Intent that sends me to another Activity. But what Context can I pass into the Intent sense I'm not calling it from an Activity class?   Intent intent = new Intent(  ? , EditMatchActivity.class)

Comment: `Intent intent = new Intent(MainAcivity.this, EditActivity.class);` I use this line to open another activity

Comment: I can't pass MainActivity.this as a context. I"m creating all of this from inside a ViewHolder inside an Adapter class, not an Activity.

Comment: In your ListAdapter make it like this `private final Activity context;
public ListAdapter(Activity context)
{
  this.context = context;
  ...
}`

in your activity pass context
`ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(Main2Activity.this);`

Comment: and to open the `Intent` you will use this line `Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditActivity.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Android Recyclerview With onItemClickListener, Why we cant try this is working like ListView only.

Source : http://sapandiwakar.in/recycler-view-item-click-handler/

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements
        RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }
}
```